# Couldn’t get GCM token because of banned servers

Tags: react-native, expo

I have this problem for so long but I figured out that in my country some of the servers has been banned by the country and I guess that expo’s servers are one of them.
I’m getting this error only when the user doesn’t use proxy and every time the users use proxy they can get push token with no problem.
Is there any solution for that?Why does getting push token by expo needs to connect to server?
Is there any other way to get user’s token of theirs devises?

Comment: Hello Hamid and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add more information to your question: code, country of origin, country of destination and if you are paying for service.

Comment: @TarickWelling, Sorry for that. I'm from Iran and my customers are also Iranian people. I have tried Expo documentation code for getting push Token and I'm not using payed services.

Comment: @TarickWelling , I find out the problem.The problem is that GCM has blocked iran so we can't connect to their servers except using VPN. Is there any way to get GCM without connecting directly to GCM servers?

Comment: @hamid Did you find any solution for his problem?
Please post the answer if you found any solution.